# Importing modules from a neighbouring folder in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have put the question in the figure below:

[image]

**EDIT**
The question put next to the figure is:

How do I make script_A1 import a function from script_B2?

Similar questions have been asked before. But most answers suggest to add the module/script/package(whatever) to the PATH variable. For example:

```
sys.path.append('...')
```

But adding the module to the PATH variable just feels so wrong. I do not want to alter my system in any way. When my application closes, I want my Python environment to be clean and 'untouched'. I'm afraid that adding uncontrolled modules to the PATH variables on my system will cause headaches later on.

Thank you for helping me out :-)

Comment: Appending to `sys.path` isn't a persistent change; it won't do anything to `PATH` or `PYTHONPATH`. It's probably not the best way to go about this, but it's not going to have the problems you're worried about.

Comment: I don't know why someone downvoted my question. Please, leave a comment before making the downvote, to explain what I can do better. I'm a reasonable person. I'm willing to listen.

Comment: Your answer should be in text form, not uploaded as an image: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318618/proposal-adding-the-text-in-text-form-in-the-close-reason

Comment: Yeah, I've put a lot of text next to the figure..

Comment: @K.Mulier that text is not searchable by google and other site crawlers. Your question should be in actual text. You have put your text in an image, which helps no one.

Comment: Oh, okay,
Give me a second,
I will edit it..

Comment: @DarrickHerwehe , thank you for your useful tip. I've edited my question :-)

Comment: @DarrickHerwehe, please undo your downvote. I've edited the question, and even upvoted your useful comments. I'm afraid that the -1 score will lead to this question no longer getting any attention :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a trick of adding the top folder to path:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('..')
import folderB.something
```

You can also use [imp.load_source](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html) if you prefer.

Comment: Someone commented: _"Appending to sys.path isn't a persistent change; it won't do anything to PATH or PYTHONPATH"_. Is this true? Because that would be awesome.

Comment: Yes, it won't actually change your system variables. It will only affect your current script process.

Comment: That's great. Thank you.
What is that last part of your answer? About using _imp.load source_?

Comment: Its a method to load modules by path: "Load and initialize a module implemented as a Python source file and return its module object." - read the link I attached there are many useful functions there you might want to check ot

Comment: Thank you very much! I will test it tomorrow at work, but I'm pretty confident that it will be allright. I'll check your answer now as the correct one, since you've been really helpful. In case it doesn't work out, would you be willing to further assist?

Comment: Sure no problem, but in the future please accept answers only after you see they actually work :)

Comment: Yes, you're right.
It's my second week on stackoverflow, so I'm still getting to know the system. Thank you for the tips. And thank you for the good help. Your answers were really helpful.

Comment: Hi @Ness,
Unfortunately it doesn't work :(.  When I print out the path after sys.path.append('..'), I just get '..' added to the list of python paths. But not the parent directory.

Comment: that's the expected behavior, those '..' will allow you to import from one folder up. did you try to import what you needed? this should work.

Comment: I tried it, but unsuccesfully. Maybe I did something wrong? I don't know. I've found another way to tackle the issue. I've posted it in an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved the issue.

In the following way, you can append the parent directory to the PATH. Put this at the top of `script_A1`:

```
import sys
import os
myDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
parentDir = os.path.split(myDir)[0]
if(sys.path.__contains__(parentDir)):
    print('parent already in path')
    pass
else:
    print('parent directory added')
    sys.path.append(parentDir)

# Now comes the rest of your script
```

You can verify that the parent directory `myProject` is indeed added to the PATH by printing out:

```
    print(sys.path)
```

Since the parent directory `myProject` is now part of the PATH, you can import scripts/modules/whatever from any of its subdirectories. This is how you import `script_B2` from `folder_B`:

```
import folder_B.script_B2 as script_B2
```

After closing your application, you can verify if your Python environment is restored to its initial state. just print the PATH again and check if the directory you had appended is gone.

Answer (score 0):

As Ronen Ness mentioned, you can use [imp](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imp.html) to achieve what you want. At the start of *script_A1.py*:

```
import imp 
file, path, description = imp.find_module("folderB", ["./folderB"])
imp.load_module("folderB", file, path, description)
from folderB.script_B2 import *
```

Answer (score -1):

Put this at the top of script_A1;

`from folderB.script_B2 import YourClass as your_class`

Comment: I'm sorry, but this approach doesn't work. I've tried it.
But thanks anyway for the help ;-)