# How to import my own modules into a scrapy project?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to write a scrapy spider with multiple pipelines. I select which pipeline to use with an attribute of the spider. The attribute is of an enum type I wrote myself. The problem now is importing that enum in the pipeline classes. Every time I try to import it I get the following error:

```
from data.file_types import FileTypes
builtins.ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'data'
```

I already tried different variations to place the enum class and switched between relative and absolute imports. If I place the enum class in a own package independent of the scrapy package I can import and use the enum if I run the pipeline files directly but I still get an error if I want to run the spider over the shell.

My current project structure is:

```
noveldownloader:
    data
        enum_file.py
        __init__.py
    novelscraper
        novelscraper
           pipelines
           spiders
           etc
        __init__.py
        scrapy.cfg
```

And my current import is:
`from data.file_types import FileTypes`

If it helps I uploaded my code to GitHub:
https://github.com/JustACodingFox/NovelDownloader

Comment: In other words, you want to import something from a neigbour folder? This is hard, I've been struggling at this point several times. Maybe you need a `__init__.py` in the root folder and a `sys.path.append('...')` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36701958/importing-modules-from-a-neighbouring-folder-in-python)

Comment: Can you move `data` inside the outer `novelscraper` and use an absolute import?

Comment: do you mean the structure like that?

noveldownloader:
 novelscraper
   data
          enum_file.py
           __init__.py
         novelscraper
          pipelines
              spiders
             etc
          __init__.py
          scrapy.cfg

and this as import `novelscraper.data.enum_file` if yes I already tried that but sadly it didn´t work either

But the tip with the sys.path.append(`..`) worked but could you explain what it does to me? I understand that it adds the path to the directory above the current one to some system path but I don´t understand why?

Answer (score 0):

One alternative folder structure that worked for me, while modularising my code was this.

create new folder 'data' inside  `./noveldownloader/noveldownloader/`

then you can import it like this

```
from noveldownloader.data import enum_file
```

and then you can consume this function by

```
enum_file.whatever_function_to_call()
```