# Python3 imports

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking for a way to import modules so that I can run a script both from the sub-folder `project/v0` and from the root folder `project`

My file structure in python 3.6 (which is why there are no init files)

```
project
├── api.py
├── v0
│   ├── SearchEngine.py     => contains SearchEngine class
│   └── SearchEngineBE.py
```

My SearchEngineBE.py module contains

```
from SearchEngine import SearchEngine
```

My api.py module contains

```
from v0.SearchEngineBE import SearchEngineBE
```

**step1:** When from `project/v0` I run `python3 SearcheEngineBE.py` my module is correctly imported and everything goes well.

**step2:** However, when from `project` I run `python3 run api.py` I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "api.py", line 3, in <module>
    from v0.SearchEngineBE import SearchEngineBE 
  File "/xxx/project/v0/SearchEngineBE.py", line 3, in <module>
    from SearchEngine import SearchEngine
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SearchEngine'
```

How can I fix this so that both step 1 and step 2 would work ?

Comment: Get in the habit of storing your projects in a fixed, independent location, and set up your environment so that you can run your scripts without regard for what your current working directory is.

Comment: `__init__.py` is missing

Comment: @chepner : Adding code's working directory in environment is bad practice. It is helpful for developing but not for production one. If we use the proper use on `package` concept of python, we do not need an environment variables.

Comment: @chepner any advise on how to implement such a structure that is independent of the path-location of my script?

Comment: What I really meant was, don't run your code from your development directory. Deploy it first, *then* run it. "Deploy" can be as simple as making sure that `project` is a proper package, as pointed out by Harsha Biyani.

Answer (score 2):

Non-relative imports are searched by the interpreter in the current directory (and any additional search paths).

You could use relative imports in your `SearchEngineBE.py` file to let the interpreter know you want the relative module, and not a module off the import path:

```
# SearchEngineBE.py
from .SearchEngine import SearchEngine
```

The `.` lets the interpreter know that you are referencing a module relative to the current module.  You'll need at least a blank `__init__.py` file in the same directory as `SearchEngine.py` for relative imports to work though:

> The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat directories
>   containing the file as packages.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

See this guide for some more discussion: https://chrisyeh96.github.io/2017/08/08/definitive-guide-python-imports.html#absolute-vs-relative-import

**Edit:**
Without a root package, this won't work.  See this post for an alternative approach: [Importing modules from a neighbouring folder in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36701958/importing-modules-from-a-neighbouring-folder-in-python)

Comment: Unfortunately I get this when I run step 1:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SearchEngineBE.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .SearchEngine import SearchEngine
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.SearchEngine'; '__main__' is not a package

Comment: I think I've replicated your sources, and was able to get the same error. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative approach. Although I don't like the `sys.path.append('..')` it seems the only way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Add `__init__.py` to make it a `package`.
(it could be empty file : `__init__.py`)

```
project
├── __init__.py
├── api.py
├── v0
│   ├── SearchEngine.py     => contains SearchEngine class
│   └── SearchEngineBE.py
```

**Edit 1:**

try :

```
from project.v0.SearchEngine import SearchEngine
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As stated in question, I use python 3.6 for which init files are not needed anymore. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Robycool : Thanks for letting me know. I did not know this. I have modified my answer. This with edit1.

Comment: I get the ModuleNotFoundError (no module named project). The following command works for step 2 but not anymore for step 1: `from v0.SearchEngine import SearchEngine`. The problem seems to be that when I run a script from a sub-package, it cannot find the parent package.