# Importing python code from different folder

Tags: python

I have 2 folders in the same directory and each folder have a python code. For example  Folder A with abc.py and B with xyz.py. How do I call the code from xyz.py? I tried `from A.abc.py import *`. Do i need to specify the path somewhere?

Comment: from where do you call your python code?

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36701958/importing-modules-from-a-neighbouring-folder-in-python solve your problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing modules from a neighbouring folder in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36701958/importing-modules-from-a-neighbouring-folder-in-python)

Comment: Folder A & B are in same directory . I have to call the code abc.py from  xyz.py

Answer (score 0):

For absolute imports, the imported module needs to be in a folder that the PYTHONPATH environment variable points to.
You can do a relative import.

```
# This is file xyz.
# relative import
from ..A import abc
```